# AndroidManifest permission as displayed in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

Where is it possible to find a mapping between an android manifest specified permission to its group and the text as it is displayed to the user when downloading the published application form the Google Play store?

Example:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Translates into:

```
Network communication
Full network access
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?Manifest.permission
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

[App permission](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6014972?hl=en)

Comment: He means on permissions, but the text it parses to. 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` is equal to "_Network communication_
and _Full network access_"

Comment: FiN is correct. I would like to know how it would be displayed to the user once he downloads the app in Google Play

Answer (score 0):

Hmm the description text for the permission I found:

- [Permission Groups](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/perms?lang=en)

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on the **Google Play** version and **Android version**. I recommend you try [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsecure.app.permissions.privacy) or [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.heagoo.pmaster). You can read description of all permissions which you use in your app.

Comment: Im sorry but thats not what I asked. I want a mapping between the permisssions and what the user sees. I understand this may vary between versions. I would be satisfied with a mapping to 1 versions, preferably as new as possible.